# Remove path from pip or PYTHONPATH to install packages in seperate python directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, numpy

I installed python in a separate directory `/home/usr/Downloads/python3`
but now when I'm trying to install `numpy` in this separate python by running:

```
/home/usr/Downloads/python3/bin/python3 -m pip install numpy
```

It is showing `numpy` already installed as `numpy` is installed in my original `python3.7`

So, is there any way I can modify and tell pip to install `numpy` separately for Downloads/python ?

So far I have looked at how to modify `sys.path` in python by adding `.pth` file or `sys.path.append`/`remove`. Also I tried creating virtual python env instead of seperate python installation but it also has the same problem as `numpy` is installed in original `python3.7`.

Comment: When you tried using a virtual environment, what command did you use? According to the docs, unless you use the `--system-site-packages` flag, you should be getting an isolated environment with no access to the base installation.

Comment: I reset PYTHONPATH to default now it is working using virtual env